# How do I force max 4 decimals without rounding up in C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, parameters

Example variables:

```
var example1 =  1,12345638282382384;
var example2 = 12,12;
var example3 = 30,19999;
```

Result what I want:

```
example1 = 1,1234;
example2 = 12,12; // 12,1200 would be better but isn't that important)
example3 = 30,1999;
```

What is the issue? I got more than 4 decimal numbers, but I want to only see 4 decimals. I search around the internet, but I only see examples of rounding up & full numbers getting a comma, while my example already have the comma's.

Furthermore, I am a student/junior developer and at least tried to search around before asking, hopefully someone knows the answer.

Comment: Multiply by 10000, `Math.Truncate`, divide by 10000.

Comment: c# or c? Make up your mind please.

Comment: What is this: `var example1 =  1,12345638282382384;`? There's a comma there instead of a dot. Does *I want to only see 4 decimals* imply that you want to **format** these numbers, for presentation, in an UI (tagged `winforms`)? If that's the case, use the `ToString()` overload that allows to specify the number of decimal places (e.g., `example2.ToString("N4", [CultureInfo]`), where `[CultureInfo]` is a CultureInfo that uses a comma as the decimal separator. -- Specify the actual Type instead of `var` .

Comment: *Don't* multiply and divide. [Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0) allows you to specify the rounding behavior you want, eg ` Math.Round(example1,4,MidpointRounding.ToZero)` produces `1.1234`

Comment: `MidpointRounding.ToZero` is not avaible in .NET framework 4.8, only in .NET ... so you have to use divide if you are on 4.8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Math.Round](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=net-6.0) allows you to specify the rounding behavior you want, eg `Math.Round(example1,4,MidpointRounding.ToZero)` produces `1.1234`.

```
C# > var example1 =  1.12345638282382384;

C# > Math.Round(example1,4)
╭─✔──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ 1.1235                                                         │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
C# >  Math.Round(example1,4,MidpointRounding.ToZero)
╭─✔──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
│ 1.1234                                                         │
╰────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯
```

Answer (score 0):

If you desperately want to avoid rounding, I'd do what user18387401 suggested in their comment, but also use some string formatting to always display 4 decimals (even if those 4 decimals are `0000`):

```cs
public static double TruncateDigits(double value, int places)
{
    var integral = Math.Truncate(value);
    var fraction = value - integral;
    
    var multiplier = (double)Math.Pow(10, places);
    var truncatedFraction = Math.Truncate(fraction * multiplier) / multiplier;

    return integral + truncatedFraction;
}

// Usage
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:N4}", TruncateDigits(example1, 4)));
```

[Link to dotnetfiddle showing this off](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RQg71n)

If you're OK with always rounding down, I'd highly suggest thinking about rounding instead of doing this as rounding does the same as this does. [Panagiotis Kanavos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72172670/9363973) shows how to do that